# Laravel @include controller data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, include

I'm trying to receive data on a sidebar that is included in the blade template but i'm not getting any data delivered. I've tried adding `@include('admin.sidebar',['message_counter' => $message_counter])` and in the sidebar view show as `{{$message_counter}}`. I'm getting a `Undefined variable: message_counter`.

My router:

```
Route::get('/admin/sidebar', [
        'uses' => 'MessagesController@counter',
        'as' => 'admin.sidebar'

    ]);
```

My controller

```
use App\Message;

public function counter()
    {
        $message_counter = Message::where('status', 0)->get();
        return view('admin.sidebar')->with('message_counter', $message_counter);
    }
```

My View

`<span class="menu-collapsed">Messages <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary ml-2"> {{$message_counter}} </span></span>`

What i ultimately intend to do is to show the amount of unread messages in the sidebar of the administrator backend, which is `@include`in every page.

It may be because i'm accessing two different controllers everytime I enter any page on the admin backend.

I've looked into [Including Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures) but i'm probably missing something silly or not understanding some key concept, help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: I think this is inconvenient and unrecommendable. This is just to answer the question, you can scroll down to see other answers or approach.

**Controller**

```
public function counter()
{
    $message_counter = Message::where('status', 0)->get();
    return view('admin.sidebar');
}
```

**View**

```
@php 
    $message_counter = App\Message::where('status', 0)->get();
@endphp

Messages <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary ml-2"> {{$message_counter}} </span></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried with compact but i still get `Undefined variable: message_counter` in the sidebar with `{{$message_counter}}` in `resources\views\admin\sidebar.blade.php`

Comment: well, that works, but like you said, it's not "pretty" i'd rather do this "the right way" if possible! But we're close!

Comment: @DavidCova glad it works, well you have second option now if none works. Try to wait the answers for others :)

Answer (score 0):

With a View Composer: add this to App\Providers\AppServiceProvider@boot()

```
View::composer('admin.sidebar', function ($view) {
            $message_counter = Message::where('status', 0)->get();
            $view->with([''message_counter' => $message_counter]);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm still getting `Undefined variable: message_counter` in the sidebar with `{{$message_counter}}`

Comment: @DavidCova Add your resources/views/admin/sidebar.blade.php please

Comment: `<span class="menu-collapsed">Messages <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary ml-2">
                       {{$message_counter}}
                        </span></span>`

Comment: @DavidCova  and your view cache is clear?  ```php artisan cache:clear```

Comment: @DavidCova What happens when you try? ->with(['message_counter' => 'foo'])

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: message_counter` . I think what's causing this is the router accessing two controllers, one for the included sidebar and one for the page. I don't think that's possible

Comment: @DavidCova No, that's not how it would be structured.  Is this an AJAX based UI or blade?  If you have template.blade.php @include(sidebar.blade.php, [associative array])  Then your controller can only return template.blade.php

Comment: @DavidCova The way we've laid everything out in this Q&A, you should currently be able to hit <url>/admin/sidebar in a browser and see only the sidebar

Comment: it's blade, the main file has 


extends('global.main')
section('head')
endsection
section('content')
include('admin.sidebar')
endsection
section('foot')
endsection

This main file, depending on the page, goes trough a controller, thing is, the sidebar also goes through a controller, that's where i think the issue comes from, maybe it's only loading one

Comment: accessing just the sidebar route i can get it to work, the problem is when it includes in other files going trough other controllers

Comment: @DavidCova Given your expressed interest in doing things the right way - check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers.  View Composers can pass data to a template whenever it loads - no matter how it is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way
**In Route:**

```
Route::get('/admin/sidebar', 'MessagesController@counter');
```

**In Controller**

```
use App\Message;

public function counter()
{
  $message_counter = Message::where('status', 0)->get();
  return view('admin.sidebar', compact('message_counter));
}
```

And your view is ok.. Try this and if it is not working please let me know....